# How to fix get_the_category function returning incorrect slug?

Tags: functions, categories, permalinks

So, I'm having an issue where using the get_the_category function is returning an incorrect slug. My code snippet is as so:

```
 <?php $category_detail=get_the_category($post->ID);
        foreach($category_detail as $cd){?>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="<?php echo $cd->slug ?>"><?php echo $cd->cat_name; ?></a> 
   </li><?php }
```

The issue is that the category slug doesn't reflect my site's permalink settings, and returns: `"mysite.com/category-name"` and not `"mysite.com/category/category-name".` I am not sure why the category permalink is being truncated, as the category pages work correctly, but this function is outputting them incorrectly, The slug in question here is for regular posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as I could see it, is not with the `get_the_category()` function. Instead, it's the way you output the category archive link: `href="<?php echo $cd->slug ?>"` — you should instead use [`get_category_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_link/) to get the correct URL of the category archive page. Example:

```php
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_category_link( $cd ) ); ?>">
```